# Iterate Json ResponseText in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

My CoffeeScript

```
errorList = @state.errors.responseText
  for own key, value of errorList
    console.log "#{key} -> #{value}"
```

My errorList variable=`{"link":["is invalid"]}`

When I run this code, in output iterate each char in this errorList. How Can I get "link -> is invalid" ?

Comment: `"#{key} -> #{value[0]}"` ?

Comment: Have you ensured that `responseText` is parsed as JSON? It sounds like you are iterating through a string instead of an object. Use `errorList = JSON.parse(@state.errors.responseText)` or `$.parseJSON` if you are using jQuery and need legacy browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your responseText property is a String, which isn't yet an iterable Object.
To convert this (valid) JSON String to an Object we can iterate, you should call JSON.Parse.

The following should work in your case

```
errorList = JSON.parse @state.errors.responseText
  for own key, value of errorList
    console.log "#{key} -> #{value}"
```

Output:

```
link -> is invalid
```